# Gzip Failed Response and Strikethrough

Tags: php, json, gzip

I have a strange issue I am hoping someone has seen before. I am making my own little api to retrieve information from one of my dbs.

It returns a multidimensional array with approximately 500 results mainly from one table with 10,00 odd rows that it checks. Once I have formed the array I then using the following code to gzip the response.

```
echo gzencode(json_encode($result),9);
```

90% of the time the gzipped info is displayed on the page as expected (a load of nonsense!).

But occasionally and I am having issues replicating this, I get a response that looks relatively normal however, after a certain point, say a quarter of the way down the page, the text is bold and has a strikethrough.

[image]

Has anyone else experienced issues with this or similar to this?

Answer (score 1):

add before echo:

```
header("Content-Encoding: gzip");
```

Answer (score 1):

Could it be a random strikethrough tag appears in the output?

```
<s>
```